# Pentaho ETL whit postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, etl, pentaho

I’m doing an ETL with Pentaho where I use several transformations and a job that executes these transformations. But when an error occurs in the process, the previous transformations that did not have a problem are saved in the PostgreSQL database. I want it to do a rollback if one of these transformations fails and a commit if these transformations are completed correctly

I tried error handling in each transaction and aborting the job in the job, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

In Pentaho, you can restart jobs using **Checkpoints**. The process to enable checkpoints in Pentaho is provided in the [official wiki page](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Products/Use_checkpoints_to_restart_jobs). Checkpoints table keeps track of your PDI jobs and in case of failures restarts from the point of failure.